# It's difficult to read the vote count of an answer that was awarded a bounty:

Tags: bug, bounty, voting, accepted-answer

Today an answer of mine was awarded a bounty, now that the answer's score count badge is blue, the green vote count is impossible to read:

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Here's what it looks like when zoomed:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the score count section only:

[image]

It's only possible to read this when the screen is on maximum brightness (`100`) and impossible to read on the lowest brightness (`-1`), which is what I always use.

I'd like to add that this is also a problem in night mode as the blue is rendered as orange and the green as violet:

[image]

Which might be difficult for people with certain types of colour blindness to tell apart.

---

To fix this problem, I'd like to suggest changing the colour to gold (`#FFD700`) for accepted:

[image]

And white (`#FFF`) for unaccepted:

[image]

As you can see, this is also a safe combination for night mode and `-1` brightness:

[image]
[image]

The problem doesn't occur on [the post itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56305980/10415695), it only happens on my [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10415695/logicalbranch?tab=reputation).